# Magento displays current store only search results in multi store website

Tags: catalog, catalogsearch, store-view

i have multiple store views, one website and i want the search results to be able to show results from different store views.  one store view is in english and the other in chinese.  if a customer searches on the chinese store view but in english, i want results from the english store view to show.  they don't though because these products in the chinese store view are written in chinese but it does not search the english text of these products.

any help please

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove

```
->addStoreFilter()
```

in Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer::prepareProductCollection() method.